# Asked question more recently than they have been seen

Tags: bug

I noticed something odd and just spot checked with several questions.

If you click a question link and see **asked 7 mins ago** and click the user name to bring up the profile it states **seen 12 mins ago**.  What's up with that? Then the next was **asked 1 mins ago** and **seen 12 mins ago**, so it's not a consistent time gap.  The next was **just now** and **14 mins**.

Why is the **seen** not accurate.

Comment: Caching.  Always caching.

Comment: Server-side caching the profile page and not the question page?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: Makes sense, just inconsistent.

Comment: consistent caching is as frequent as bug-free programs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "last seen" stat on a user's profile is only updated upon visiting when the value exceeds 15 minutes. When the value is less than 15 minutes, you can essentially treat it as saying "online now" since there is no way of knowing when their last visit actually was within that 15-minute timeframe.

Comment: Good to know thanks!  Oh, and how exactly do sunglasses confuse you?

Comment: Because they should be called "no-sun-glasses".

Comment: @AbraCadaver It's a reference to a joke about one of my old Gravatars.